Generating a recursive formula for solutions to this equation
Given an equation:
$y^2 = -x^3 + ((6n+3) \cdot x - (36n^3 + 54n^2 + 27n - 4))^2 $ where $n,x,y$ are non-zero integers,
for which value(s) of $n$ and $x$ is the term $\dfrac{(2(36n^3 + 54n^2 + 27n - 4))}{x} $ an integer?
I am aware of a set of solutions for $(n,x,y)$ that answer this problem being $(77,26578,757473)$ for positive numbers though this could not be the only possible solution.
Interesting enough, when I assume $y=0$, and test an already known value for $n = 77$ into the above equation, my value for $x$ is $26657.63$ which compared to the value of $26578$, is a margin of error of around $0,30$%.
Based on this observation and assumption that $y=0$, I substituted arbitrary values of n into the equation and whatever value I had for x for each respective case, I tried using the idea of recursive formulas to generate a general polynomial formula for x. (do note that x should be an even function) which, with the incorporation of chatgpt, I had $x(n)= 4.435n^2 + 4.705n + 0.23$ and when you apply this to the divisibility problem as posed above, i had a linear equation of $(16.348n + 7.772)$.
https://chatgpt.com/share/676abdee-d49c-8003-88c8-cdd92e347268
(when you open the link, the ending part where I ask a question and it gives approx. $0,17000...$ and onwards should be ignored, that has nothing to do with this question.)
Given that, a set of integer solutions have been given as above, there could be more desired values of $(n,x,y)$ unknown of and I wanted to come up with such a formula for $x$ at least for positive numbers so that for certain values of $n$ like $77$ for instance,I get exactly an integer solution, and for other values of n,which won't yield integer solutions for the whole equation for y above, it returns real numbers in as expected, which from the look of things is quadratic and should as such, be able to a good divisor of $2(36n^3 + 54n^2 + 27n - 4)$ as asked above to yield a much accurate linear function.
Are there better ways of improving or refining the recursive formulas  I came up with for $x(n)$ and the linear equation I came up with?

Chatgpt is not a suitable tool for mathematics.  Don't believe anything it tells you.

The OP wishes to solve,
$$−u^3+\big((6n+3) u−(36n^3+54n^2+27n−4)\big)^2 = v^2\tag1$$
for integer $(n,u,v)$, with the divisibility constraint that $D=\dfrac{2(36n^3+54n^2+27n−4)}u=\,\text{Integer}.\,$ Note: The reason for the change of variables from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ will be clear in a moment.

For those curious, we reverse-engineer how the OP got the equation in the first place. This is just a sequel to his 2023 post where he gives two simultaneous equations,
$$12x^2 - 6x y^2 + y(y^3 - 51) - 12k = 0\\
z^2 = (y^3 - 51)^2 - 288k x$$
Eliminating $k$, I find we get the rather elegant,
$$-288x^3 + (51 + 12xy - y^3)^2 = z^2\tag2$$
which makes me curious where this system arises from. For $|y|<1000$, user Dmitry Ezhov found $17$ solutions, the first one of which is,
$$\quad (x,\,y,\,z) = (-488917,\; -984,\; 8882365635)$$
However, with the change of variables,
\begin{align}
x &= u/2\\
y &= 3(2n+1)\\
z &= 6v\end{align}
then $(2)$ transforms to $(1)$,
$$−u^3+\big((6n+3) u−(36n^3+54n^2+27n−4)\big)^2 = v^2\tag1$$
which is just the equation in this new post. Thus, we can check the solutions from the old post. For example, using Ezhov's 16th and 17th solutions with $y=3(2\times77+1)=465,$
$$(x,y) = (13289,\, 465)\\
(x,y) = (-122317,\, 465)$$
then we recover two of R. Israel's even solutions $u=2x$,
$$(u,n) = (26578,\, 77)\\ 
(u,n) = (-244634,\, 77)$$
After transformation, $6$ out of Israel's $9$ solutions also satisfy $(2)$, but only $2$ out of Ezhov's $17$ solutions satisfy the divisibility constraint $D$. (Note: The constraint $D$ seems arbitrary as it does not appear in the old post from a year ago.)
P.S. Since $(1)$ can be treated as an elliptic curve given a suitable fixed $n$ such as $n=77$, then one can indeed find a recursive formula, but it will only yield infinitely many rational (not integer) $u$.

I approached the problem like this:
Given an integer $n$, you want $x$ to be a divisor of $2 (36 n^3 + 54 n^2 + 27 n - 4)$.  For each of those divisors, compute $−x^3+((6 n+3) x−(36 n^3+54 n^2+27 n−4))^2$ and check whether that is a square.
For $n$ from $-10^5$ to $10^5$, the successes were
$$ \eqalign{ n &= -21406,&  x & = 695796037, & y & = 263081873181774\cr
 n &= -21406, & x & = -932700452, & y & = 473731151026902\cr n &= -21406, & x & = -768410189684, & y & = 680823338417964102\cr
 n &= 77, & x &= 26578, & y & = 757473\cr
 n &= 77, & x &= -172757, & y & = 120757143\cr
 n &= 77, & x &= -244634, & y & = 177971235\cr}
$$
[EDIT] Looking farther, I found three more solutions:
$$ \eqalign{n = 177359, &x = 122903311663, & y = 55242703429596903\cr
 n = 177359, & x = -394006236278, & y = 667629580151683131\cr
 n = 177359, & x = -3332153859914, & y = 7143956273270250687\cr} $$

Great! I'll try out your idea and attempt to make a recursive formula out of that.

@Robert The OP asked a similar question in this post which can be reduced to solving $$ -288x^3 + (51 + 12xy - y^3)^2 = z^2$$ of which $17$ solutions were found. (The variables $x,y$ are not identical to yours.) It can easily be transformed to the one in this new post, but the OP added a divisibility constraint. Details in my answer below.
